# Python3 TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, odoo, odoo-11

I'm porting odoo 11, python 2.7 to python 3. I have been edited an addon which has belongs to odoo, python code.

The code is:

```
vat = invoice.partner_id.vat or ''
vat = list(filter(lambda x: x.isnumeric(), vat[:2])) + vat[2:]
```

Error is:

```
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list
```

How can I fix that, what is wrong with this code? Please help me.

Comment: Can you please update your question with possible inputs.

Comment: sorry for forgot, I updated that.

Comment: Maybe change `list` to `str` would solve

Comment: @Carcigenicate But how? When trying this i'm getting same error.

Comment: @HouLu I tried but not worked.

Comment: What value does `invoice.partner_id.vat` have and what would the expected output be? You are concatenating a list (from `list(filter(....))` to a string (the slice `vat[2:]`. You'd probably want to convert the list back to a string first (`''.join(...)`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
list(filter(lambda x: x.isnumeric(), vat[:2]))
```

This operation above **always** returns the **list**.

```
vat = invoice.partner_id.vat or ''
```

- seems, this operation returns str (because of `or ''`).

If you expect that your `type(vat)==list`, you should use

```
vat = invoice.partner_id.vat or []
```

If you expect `type(vat)==str`, you should convert your filtered list to `str`,  for example

```
"".join(list(filter(lambda x: x.isnumeric(), vat[:2]))) + vat[2:]
```

Comment: man, you're amazing. you are totally right. thank you so much!

Answer (score -1):

Use line

```
vat = invoice.partner_id.vat or ''
#convert string to list
vat = [x for x in val]
vat = list(filter(lambda x: x.isnumeric(), vat[:2])) + vat[2:]
```

to convert string to list first.

Comment: I highly doubt they wanted a list as output. `[x for x in val]` is... pointless when you could just use `list(val)`, and only the `vat[2:]` slice would need converting.